# PySimpleGUI serial scanner with simple GUI

Tags: pyserial, pysimplegui

I try to write my first program in Python and currently I am struggling with simple serial reader which will help me in work. I create program dirctly in raspberry Pi4 running raspbian and the same time I test if it works with other device. The idea is to:

Connect Raspberry to device via serial port - WORKING,

Repeatably send via serial port chart "C" and "\R" to trigger status update in device which I want to read - WORKING.

Check if in readed data there is triggered value (**DI_29_ON** or **DI_29_OFF** for example, because there are hundrests more of them) - WORKING

Present **DI_29** status (**ON** or **OFF**) with colour button with PySimpleGUI - Not working perfectly - I have to reload generated window to update status.

I think my problem is to understand how handle with simplegui functions and how to create event or automatic layout update. The problem is that at this moment I am out of ideas how to solve this issue and finish my program... Here's my working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg



if __name__ == '__main__':
        ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',\
        baudrate=115200,\
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        xonxoff=True,\
            timeout=1)
        
        while True:
            
            line = ser.read(10000).decode('ascii').rstrip()           
            #print(line)
            if 'DI_29_ON' in line:
                
                sta = 'ON'
                layout = [[sg.Text('DI_29 Status:', key ='-OUT-')],
                          [sg.Button(sta)]]
                window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

                event, values = window.read()
                
            else:
                sta = 'OFF'
                layout = [[sg.Text('DI_29 Status:', key ='-OUT-')],
                          [sg.Button(sta)]]
                window = sg.Window('Title', layout)

                event, values = window.read()
                
                
                #print(sta)
              
            ser.write('c'.encode('ascii'))
            ser.write('\r'.encode('ascii'))
            #time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Update status by multi-threading, and generate an event and value by `window.write_event_value(key, value)`. Process all events in event loop to do something or update status.

Comment: Thx Jason, I try this